# Mysql fulltext search: To where clause, or not to where clause?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have 2 mysql fulltext search queries that return a different set of results.

```
SELECT e.id AS e__id, 
MATCH(e.subtitle, e.summary, e.title, e.prtext) AGAINST ('lorem') 
FROM exhibitions e
```

will return a predictable set of 7 rows (I have 10 overall in the table), each having the id of a record that contains the word 'lorem'.

However, when I introduce a where clause

```
SELECT e.id 
FROM exhibitions e 
WHERE MATCH(e.subtitle, e.summary, e.title, e.prtext) AGAINST ('lorem')
```

No rows are returned.

What is the difference between these two queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the issue was I had a number of fulltext indicies on my table structure, when I really only needed one.  Here is a correct query with a `where` and an `and` clause:

```
SELECT  e.id AS e__id,
    e.enabled AS e__enabled,
    e.rewrite AS e__rewrite,
    e.title AS e__title,
    e.subtitle AS e__subtitle,
    e.summary AS e__summary,
    e.type AS e__type,
    e.feature_home AS e__feature_home,
    e.date_start AS e__date_start,
    e.date_end AS e__date_end,
    e.prtext AS e__prtext,
    e.last_update AS e__last_update,
    e.file_id1 AS e__file_id1,
    e.file_id2 AS e__file_id2,
    e.file_id3 AS e__file_id3,
    e.file_id4 AS e__file_id4,
    e.file_id5 AS e__file_id5
FROM exhibitions e
WHERE  MATCH(e.subtitle, e.summary, e.title, e.prtext) AGAINST ('lorem')
       AND e.enabled = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding * IN BOOLEAN MODE

```
SELECT *,MATCH (ft_search_field) AGAINST ('lorem*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS Score
FROM table_name
WHERE MATCH (ft_search_field) AGAINST ('lorem*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```